# Is it possible to use react-navigation to slideDown new view from top?

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native navigation, for navigating between screen.
I want that a new screen will slideDown from the top of the screen.
Is it possible?

This is my code:

```
const ModalStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Profile: {
    path: 'people/:name',    
    screen: MyProfileScreen,
  },
});
```

Comment: It should be possible, any help?